# Android Studio --Cannot tokenize targeted directory '#'. Expecting either '<name>' or '<name>#<key>_<value>' format

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, apk, signed

My app is not bundling after I installed a clean version of Android Studio. I am guessing this is in an .xml file somewhere,  Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you remove "#" signs in the files in your "assets" directory?

Comment: I have found nothing in my assets folder. <name> & <key> remind em of something you would find in an info.plist . I have completely uninstalled Android Studios , reverted my git head, cleaned gradle. I am stumped.

Comment: Do you know what the "targeted" directory is when running a build for a bundle?

Answer (score 2):

The same way you can target resources to certain type of devices (e.g. `res/drawable-mdpi/` for devices with mdpi screen density), you can do this with assets as well with the App Bundle. To achieve this, asset directories must follow the following name pattern:

```
assets/<name>#<key>_<value>/...
```

Where `<key>` can be for example "tcf" (for "texture compression format") and `<value>` would be for example "etc1" (for compression format ETC1). With this example, files in that directory would only be served to devices that support that compression format.

This is an advanced feature of the App Bundle.

Basically, if one of your assets directory contains a '#' sign, it will try to interpret it as one of those targeted directories and try to parse the directory accordingly to the pattern above. If it doesn't match the pattern, it throws an exception.

In your case, it looks like you have a directory named '#' in your `assets` directory. If you can't find it, it may be pulled by own of your library dependencies.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks!! You pointed me in the right direction , I looked everywhere for that '#' . I ended up deleting the repo off my computer and re cloning it and it worked immediately!!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by deleting the repo that had my source code in it. Our Cordova folder and our source code are 2 different repos. ThenI cloned it back in and it worked. Hope this helps someone else. I spent too many hours on this.